# Async load components locally and alias the name

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am migrating to vue.js 3 and did not find a solution to get this working:

In Vue.js 2 I was able to load a component like this and assign a alias name:

```
components: {
        checkbox: () => import('./CheckboxField'),
}
```

In Vue.js 3 I have to use a [new way](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#async-components) to import the component.

This is what I did for now:

```
components: {
        AsyncComponent: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
            import('./CheckboxField.vue')
        )
    },
```

But I don't get how I can give this `CheckboxField` an alias-name like I did before.

Comment: what do you mean by alias name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `AsyncComponent` *is* the component name, isn't it? So:

```
components: {
    checkbox: defineAsyncComponent(() =>
        import('./CheckboxField.vue')
    )
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. :-D Yes, you are completely right. My IDE displayed, that 'checkbox' is not imported, so I guessed I was wrong - but indeed my IDE was wrong ;-)